# Does any one have idea about "Promote To Article" option in Napili Template ?

Tags: community

I have enabled  Answers Settings "Allow users to create an article from a reply" under Knowledge Setting . But I am not able to see Promote To Article option for replies.Is this a limitation with Napili Template .